# High CPU on IIS sites

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, io, cpu

I have a webserver with 10 mvc sites that I have created. All sites "link" to the same code in a folder. So all 10 sites run on same code. This is done have different languages on the site.

My problem is that 1 site goes up to use 40-60% of the CPU for a few minutes. Then it drops down and another sites rises in CPU. Normally the sites use 300mb in w3wp process, but sometimes rises to 8-900mb!

There's 20GB of memory, 18,9 is constantly used. There is also a SQL server running that takes 13GB.

The site is a MVC 3 site. Uses caching on the SQL data.

Every site has its own pool.

I know its a very vague question. But can anyone see any obvious problems with this setup?

Why does the CPU rise periodically?

There are about constantly 100-150 users on the sites.

Any ideas or thought would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CPU utilization is result of web application so application developers would know best where is the problem. If application developers aren't "in-house" you as administrator will have to find is there problem in setup (less likely) or in application (more likely in my opinion).

Since IIS **NEED** tool from Microsoft like [IIS Tracer](http://iismonitor.motobit.com/), debugging high CPU utilization with "DebugDiag & friends" require lots of knowledge and effort.

Here is [one nice article how to troubleshoot high CPU usage](http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/performance-issues/troubleshooting-high-cpu-in-an-iis-7x-application-pool)

Do your web apps use caching ?

```
OutputCache duration="180" varybyparam="*"
```

Sorry if this isn't helpful, but I'm administrator and when IIS server have high CPU usage in 95% problem is in poor SQL queries or bad programming which we fix after analyzing **source code**.